# Delete the \n and following letters in the end of words in a list

Tags: python, string

How can I delete the `\n` and the following letters? Thanks a lot.

```
wordlist = ['Schreiben\nEs', 'Schreiben', 'Schreiben\nEventuell', 'Schreiben\nHaruki']
for x in wordlist:
    ...?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
>>> import re
>>> wordlist = ['Schreiben\nEs', 'Schreiben', \
    'Schreiben\nEventuell', 'Schreiben\nHaruki']
>>> [ re.sub("\n.*", "", word) for word in wordlist ]
['Schreiben', 'Schreiben', 'Schreiben', 'Schreiben']
```

Done via `re.sub`:

```
>>> help(re.sub)
  1 Help on function sub in module re:
  2 
  3 sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0)
  4     Return the string obtained by replacing the leftmost
  5     non-overlapping occurrences of the pattern in string by the
  6     replacement repl.  repl can be either a string or a callable;
  7     if a callable, it's passed the match object and must return
  8     a replacement string to be used.
```

Comment: I am not sure but i guess he also wants to remove the successive chars after \n

Comment: but i also want to delete the following letters after \n and ""! Thanks again

Comment: I am very glad that you help me. there are so many functions in python. you are a great help. of course i will read more about re-module now. :)

Answer (score 3):

```
[w[:w.find('\n')] fow w in wordlist]
```

few tests:

```
$ python -m timeit -s "wordlist = ['Schreiben\nEs', 'Schreiben', 'Schreiben\nEventuell', 'Schreiben\nHaruki']" "[w[:w.find('\n')] for w in wordlist]"
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.03 usec per loop
$ python -m timeit -s "import re; wordlist = ['Schreiben\nEs', 'Schreiben', 'Schreiben\nEventuell', 'Schreiben\nHaruki']" "[re.sub('\n.*', '', w) for w in wordlist]"
10000 loops, best of 3: 17.5 usec per loop
$ python -m timeit -s "import re; RE = re.compile('\n.*'); wordlist = ['Schreiben\nEs', 'Schreiben', 'Schreiben\nEventuell', 'Schreiben\nHaruki']" "[RE.sub('', w) for w in wordlist]"
100000 loops, best of 3: 6.76 usec per loop
```

**Edit:**

The solution above is completely wrong (see the comment from Peter Hansen). here the corrected one:

```
def truncate(words, s):
    for w in words:
        i = w.find(s)
        yield w[:i] if i != -1 else w
```

Comment: What an incredibly bad (i.e. totally untested) answer, given that it quietly truncates words that do NOT have a newline in them.  str.find() returns -1 in the case where there is no match, and slicing with [:-1] will return everything up to but not including the last character.  Please remove.

Comment: @Peter Hansen: thanks for your report, i was thinking how to make it one line for timeit and i forgot the correctness.

Comment: @mg, okay... just fix the for loop in the edited part now please.  "For w in in words:" has an extra "in".

Comment: You could get a small speed up (~10 %) by using `RE=re.compile(…).sub` and `[RE('', w)…]`: there is no need to look for the `sub()` method for each word.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regular expression to do so:

```
import re
wordlist = [re.sub("\n.*", "", word) for word in wordlist]
```

The regular expression `\n.*` matches the first `\n` and anything that might follow (`.*`) and replaces it with nothing.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> wordlist = ['Schreiben\nEs', 'Schreiben', 'Schreiben\nEventuell', 'Schreiben\nHaruki']
>>> [ i.split("\n")[0] for i in wordlist ]
['Schreiben', 'Schreiben', 'Schreiben', 'Schreiben']
```